# Rails CSV file compress in .gz format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip

How can we csv file compress in .gz format and save in rails.root public folder?

```
def compress_file(file_name)
  zipped = "#{file_name}.gz"
  Zlib::GzipWriter.open(zipped) do |gz|
   gz.write IO.binread(file_name)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Zlib::GzipWriter.open(zipped) do |gz|
 gz.mtime = File.mtime(file_path)
 gz.orig_name = file_path
 gz.write IO.binread(file_path)
end
```

file will save on as defined path in  `file_path` path with compressing file.